# Do we support good-faith but rudimentary questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616683/c-and-c-array-characteristic) is the post in question. It accumulated four downvotes in an hour.

### The post

The way I perceive the post, it conforms to the rules of the site

- Clearly on-topic
- Well-posed
- Shows effort through experimentation and correctly questions the results

Questioning the result is of particular importance, it is the primary deterrent against [cargo cults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

As a high school student, the OP understandably has limited experience. With that in mind, requiring OP to know where and how to do all possible research is unreasonable.

### The problem

However, the obvious problem here is the question is *undeniably* basic.

This is once again a debate on whether we support such questions.

On the one hand, from the point of view of experts, most questions about a language is basic. I suspect it being *the* reason why these experts don't ask many questions: they *know* they can get to an answer themselves, it's called "research". But there are only a handful of such experts, can we not ask a question for fear of it being "basic"?

On the other hand, votes are indicative of usefulness. We vote based on the usefulness of a post. Since the post is deemed too basic, it got downvoted.

Do we support such questions? At what point do we decide the question worthy of support? I find the line hard to draw.

Comment: The downvotes may also be caused by the title beginning with _C and C++_. I'm not familiar with those tags, but from the discussions I've seen on meta, that's a sure way to quickly accumulate downvotes.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The tag got edited out 8 minutes after the post. I'm not there right at the beginning so I don't know.

Comment: In case someone wonders, I immediately found a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620202/how-to-make-lambdas-work-with-stdnullopt) that might be deemed basic or difficult depending on your experience with C++. It is well-received.

Comment: It is being supported, it got two answers.  Even got 3 helpful votes.  Whether the answerers actually did him a favor is questionable, somebody ought to write a manual that explains how C strings work.  Which of course is the sticking point, such manuals have already been written and neither belong nor fit in an SO post.  He would be much, much better off with a link to such a manual.  We are not allowed to provide him with one, could fit in a comment.

Comment: @HansPassant "It is being supported", but what do _I_ do? If we decide this shouldn't be supported, I should downvote. If it should be supported, then I'd think either it be closed as duplicate as some canonical or answered, but not downvoted. I should even upvote since I think the question well-written.

Comment: You'll have to decide for yourself.  There is no "we", the vast majority of SO users have interest in neither the tags nor that question.  Since you objected against it getting downvoted, I suppose it is logical to upvote it.  Or do nothing, that's fine as well, like I did.

Comment: *I immediately found a new question that might be deemed basic or difficult depending on your experience with C++.* --> This is not a fair analogy, whether a question is too basic is objective. Asking about return type deduction and `std::option` already demonstrates that the asker has reasonable experience of the language to encounter this kind of problem, it's essentially different from someone not understanding how `char *` works.

Comment: @liliscent I missed the _"essentially different"_ part. I don't see a categorical difference between the two. You drew a line somewhere saying one is basic and the other isn't.

Comment: @HansPassant I did nothing. I want to vote on merit for the site. Obviously I learnt nothing from the question, neither am I interested in its answers. I'm asking if I should be encouraging these kinds of questions. Or perhaps I misunderstood and voting is just indication for personal interest.

Comment: @PasserBy There *is* a categorical difference between these 2 cases. It's not uncommon that a real C++ programmer not understanding the mechanism of type deduction or latest C++ version, it doesn't matter much in practice. But anyone having read the first 20 pages of a beginner textbook *should* understand how `char*` works.

Comment: @liliscent I could argue `std::string` is the one that should be understood, `char*` is an implementation detail. I could argue anyone should know how to write a trailing return type for a lambda, it's introduced in C++11 so it's 7 years now. How can you say with such certainty it is _objectively_ basic or not?

Comment: @PasserBy A string class without the concept of encoding is close to useless, `char*` is at the root of both C and C++, why do you think the later is an *implementation detail* ? When I said *too basic*, I meant it's essentially asking us to write a tutorial/textbook, which is already stated in the answer below.

Comment: My experience with c/c++ tag is that you face religious people who think their language is the best and they master it better than the standard. Good rule of thumb is : don’t ask in this tag or accept downvotes

Comment: Here's a great general approach: **downvote** posts that are *bad* (i.e., don't conform to expectations/standards), and simply ***ignore*** (no vote) questions you find basic or not useful for the greater programming community.  [and of course, actually take the time to **upvote** good questions that are useful!! :)]

Comment: The obvious problem is that it's tagged c++.

Comment: @theforestecologist That's specifically contrary to the help center and the site's general rules on how votes are expected to be used.  To quote the vote's tooltip, for example, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)"  You are *expected* to downvote posts that do not demonstrate research effort or that are not useful questions.  Those are a part of the standards that are expected of questions on the site.

Comment: @Servy like I said, yes, you should definitely downvote posts that don't meet SO standards (e.g., don't show research effort, don't include reproducible code, etc.). However, downvoting *well-written* (and rule-conforming) posts because you find them simple isn't a great approach given that all different levels of expertise come here seeking guidance. Just because *you* think a post is simple, doesn't mean that others won't potentially find it interesting/useful. SO is for *all* programmers. Instead of downvoting, provide a quick comment, link to helpful post, close as dupe, or just move on.

Comment: @theforestecologist I never said that you should downvote a post for being "simple".  I said that you should downvote a post for being poorly researched or not useful.  You specifically said that you shouldn't vote on a question that you feel is not useful, and I was pointing out that the voting guidelines *very specifically* say that that's exactly when you *should* be downvoting a post.  If the post is well researched, and useful (and doesn't have any other problems), but just happens to be easy or simple then that can be a great question.  Such questions are just rare.

Answer (score 40):

Call me old and grumpy, but questions like this read to me like *"I want to learn about a language but I don't want to invest the 10-20 hours it costs to read a book explaining its fundamentals"*. Or even read the chapter about strings, which might cost like a tenth of that.

Yes, of course asking a question on Stack Overflow is quicker than that. You'll get an answer in mere minutes. It clarifies one small aspect of the language, just for you.

But wait.

Does the question show *research* effort? And not only in the sense of carefully analyzing and debugging their code, but also resorting to, say, existing materials?

If I type *"how does C know"* into Google, the first thing that's suggested to me is *"when a string ends"*. There's the answer: [How does C know the end of my string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349842/how-does-c-know-the-end-of-my-string). In there it's all about `strlen()`, null-terminated strings and whatnot.

Their question shows nothing of that, hence a lack of research, hence downvotable.

Comment: By all means, be grumpy. Reading books used to be "normal", everyone knew that to gain knowledge you went to school and read books and so you just did. Good times. It also used to be normal to eat home cooked meals every day. Good times, healthier times. Now move on to the 21st century: there are chains of cheap fast food restaurants all over the world and the magic "ask question" button. Can we blame people for flocking to these low effort means to an end? Not really but that doesn't mean I have to be happy about it as lowering IQs and growing guts are the fruits of our progress :/

Comment: @Gimby SO gets a few thousand questions a day.  If even 1% of people learning programming were asking on SO every time they wanted to learn how to find the end of a C string or other such questions for the first time, that number would be an order of magnitude higher.  Asking questions like that on SO is not the norm, it's just that even having .01% of new developers doing that is still enough to cause major problems for the site.  Even if books are much less common, most people are still searching, looking at digital tutorials, or other resources designed for teaching newcomers.

Comment: To be clear to others, downvoting questions because of their lack of research is a *separate thing* from voting to close them. Rudimentary, low-research questions may be downvote-worthy, but that does not make them *off-topic*. IMHO it would be good to clarify this in the answer lest people start using this as a justification to close-vote on-topic questions just because they are basic (which is not a valid close reason).

Comment: @TylerH And rudimentary questions almost inevitably have a duplicate anyway, so should be closed as well as downvoted.

Comment: @Gimby The past always seems better. [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1227/)

Comment: @DavidG *If and only if* a question is a duplicate should it be closed as such.

Answer (score -11):

In my own very personal opinion, stackoverflow tend to be an expert place.

Rudimentary questions, as you state them, are downvoted because of that.

In my experience, this is even more the case in advanced/broad tags, such as c/c++.

I feel bad with that because well, stackoverflow is a q&a website.

If you think not knowing strlen or the basics of C strings shows a lack of research, someone else could be legitimate to downvote your question about registry allocation, because in the end, it’s a few clicks ahead in google scholar.

**You are always the rookie of someone else**.

As of these questions, I would say that really often, they are closed as duplicates.

When they are not, expert or not, it’s our duty to aknowledge the OP’s lack of experience and give him a useful answer, no matter the difficulty.

Comment: What did I just say? Immediate downvote

Comment: Basics questions are not downvoted because they're basic. They're often poorly researched, and they're downvoted because of that.

Comment: Read my answer not just one line

Comment: I read your entire answer before I downvoted.

Comment: Have a look at JavaScript tag. You’ll see millions of useless questions which are kindly answered. In c++ if you don’t ask something about an UB or ambiguity in the standard you get immediate downvotes.

Comment: So what? If a question is poorly researched, it should be downvoted. Regardless of technology stack. I don't see what your answer adds to this discussion. Are you saying it's okay to ask questions without doing proper research?

Comment: @RegisPortalez Watch the js tag for a little while. You'll see TONS of useless questions downvoted and closed. If you only look at older questions or questions that exist right now, you won't see the ones that were deleted nor will you see the current useless ones deleted. You're only looking at a snapshot.

Comment: "Have a look at JavaScript tag. You’ll see millions of useless questions which are kindly answered." Right, which is why the javascript tag is a cesspool of the same questions answered over and over again and a ton of gold badgers unwilling to mark them as duplicates.